# How to dynamically set custom CSS in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Below code is working as expected, my question is there a way to create custom class in the code instead of creating a new css file and then ref in the code?

so in other words, how can I create this class `color-change-red` in the code and I would like to keep that style within the code itself instead coming from a separate css file.

/* Html file */

```
<template>
    <!-- Modal Container -->
    <div style={isChanged}>
    <!-- Modal -->       
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS File

```
.color-change-red{
    color:rgb(185, 8, 8);
}
```

JS

```
isChanged(o, u) {
   if (o != u) {  
    return ' slds-text-align_right color-change-red'; 
   } 
    return 'slds-text-align_right';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the regular "tricks" you may have seen in older HTML still apply in LWC. Nothing's really changed in regards to how HTML works fundamentally. For example, consider [this code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/1nzP7MXY35TpYtIteW1G/src/app.js):

```
<template>
    <div onclick={setRed}>
        Sample
    </div>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  setRed(event) {
    event.target.style.color = 'rgb(185, 8, 8)'
  }
}
```

Here, we set `style.color` directly with the desired value.

I get that you're trying to highlight the element when the content has changed, but that's simply a matter of using the appropriate onchange handler in your code.

```
  handleChange(event) {
    if(event.target.value == 'hello world') {
      event.target.style.color = 'red';
    } else {
      event.target.style.color = 'black';
    }
  }
```

Though, obviously, in your code, you'd compare the old value to the new, and then determine how you want to set the value accordingly.

You definitely don't need a separate CSS file if you really don't want to.

Side note: CSS names like `color-change-red` are a bad idea. They describe what the CSS does, not what it represents. A better name would have been `is-cell-changed` or something like that.

Also, the point of CSS files are so that you can easily update the attributes without having to dig through code. I'd advise against setting styles directly like this in all but the most trivial code, really.

Comment: Thanks. But I don’t have any events to change the color it should change when when the components load. In your example you changing when the user clicks.

Comment: @NickKahn My example is meant to show how this is done, the mechanism doesn't matter. For example, you can do this in `renderedCallback()`, or as a delayed function (via `setTimeout()`) in `connectedCallback()`, or whatever else. The point is, if you want to manipulate styles on individual elements, you are free to do so without needing any CSS class at all.

Comment: I get it what you saying but I face the problem on how to set custom css through JS. So the example I posted in my question how would you set both the slds and custom class without creating the .CSS file.

Comment: @NickKahn You can't define a custom rule without a CSS file. This is treading into [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) territory. Why can't you just set the style as proscribed in my answer? Why do you need the CSS rule, and why do you not want it in a CSS file? If you're trying to set an arbitrary color, maybe you're looking for CSS variables?

Comment: The reason I was trying to avoid using the css file is because 1. It will be dependence just for one single css rule and 2. This is important functionality changing color so I don’t want anyone to mess or forgot to deploy.

Comment: @NickKahn (1) many CSS files in LWC are just a few lines long; that's a feature of composition (using smaller components to create larger ones); that's not a reason to skip CSS files. (b) What if you forgot to deploy the .html file? (hint: you can create bundles without one) What about if you deployed the wrong JS file? etc. At some point, this should be caught by build tools or QA (usually the latter). One should be using the tools given to them, and that includes CSS files.

Comment: Yes I agree that one can forget anything to deploy. I was trying to explore if I can able to avoid using css file. But I get it.

Comment: @NickKahn The only option to avoid the CSS file is as above; direct style manipulation. For a short use-case like this, I would say it's fine. A rule and style overrides behave in the exact same manner.